# Switching career from Salesforce to C#

Tags: apex, .net, job

I am having 3 years of experience as Salesforce developer. I have been working on around 20 different projects of different size (from small 10 user orgs to the largest orgs in the world) on many different roles - technical and business. I feel that there is not much more "technical" stuff for me to learn. Of course I could pursue Architect role but I feel this is not for me - I love to develop, to code. There are a lot of posts online on moving from Java/C# to Salesforce but I cannot find any article about going other way around.

I would like to become C# developer, however I am wondering if this will be a right move? What challenges should I expect? What skills/technologies would be the most useful to learn? How should I approach such a change?

Comment: This is a great question, but I don't think it fits SFSE's format because it's really not about building on the Salesforce platform and has no specific answer. I'd suggest opening a conversation on a more discussion-oriented forum.